# Why does "Tab Bar Controller" not show icons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

I am currently doing the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial about Tab Bar Controllers](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) for iOS in XCode 6.

There's a step that describes how to re-order the tab icons on the bottom bar (cp. following figure):

[image]

**But these buttons are not visible on my Interface Builder (cp. following image):**

[image]

**Any ideas why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select the Item1 view and click on the tab and select tab bar image from the Utilities. It will change the image back it happen to me.